# Imaginary roots of the equation $ax^2+x+c-a=0$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If both roots of equation $ax^2+x+c-a=0$  are imaginary and $c>-1$ then

(A) $3a > 2 + 4c$

(B) $3a < 2 + 4c$

(C) $c < a$

(D) none of these

My approach is as follow

${D^2} = 1 - 4a\left( {c - a} \right) < 0$ for imaginary roots condition

Hence $4a(c-a)>1$

$4{a^2} - 4ac + {c^2} + 1 - {c^2} < 0 \Rightarrow {\left( {c - 2a} \right)^2} + 1 - {c^2} < 0$

How do I approach from here

Comment: I have made necessary correction

Comment: Note that $D^2=4a^2-4ca+1$ is a quadratic in $a$. Since the coefficient of $a^2$ is $4$, it means that it will have negative values between roots.

Comment: write $1 - 4ac + 4 a^2  < 0 $  and complete the square

Comment: Done the following steps but still struggling

Comment: If I give you a new letter $k,$   please expand and tell me what $(2a+k)^2 $   is

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi 1) If $a, c$ are assumed to be real then you should state so in the question. 2) It sounds like "*imaginary roots*" is taken to mean non-real complex roots here, but you should clarify that in the question since an "*imaginary*" root can also mean a number of the form $i \,y \,\mid\, y \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: I copied the question as it is mentioned in the question paper. all the website has the same method as if they have copied each other. If we put x=1 we get imaginary roots

Comment: There is something hokey about the polynomial in this problem:  if the two imaginary roots are conjugate, then it _should not_ have a linear term; if the roots are imaginary and _not_ conjugate, then the linear coefficient should be _imaginary_ (the constant term _can_ be real).  So there's either a typo here or the poser of the problem was careless.